# How to create .sh script for Wildfly Server Group start and stop?

Tags: linux, shell, sh, wildfly

We are using terminal to start and stop a wildfly 16 server group where we type commands inside jboss-cli.sh

```
[root@ala-esb-app01 bin]$ ./jboss-cli.sh
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.


[disconnected /] connect

[domain@10.0.1.1:2090 /] /server-group=
evoice          is               m-web    sdesk
filemover         masterdata-batch  netshop


[domain@10.0.1.1:2090 /] /server-group=sdesk:stop-servers
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => undefined,
    "server-groups" => undefined
}



[domain@10.0.1.1:2090 /] /server-group=servicedesk:start-servers
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => undefined,
    "server-groups" => undefined
}
```

Suppose we need to create ./stop_sdesk.sh AND ./start_sdesk.sh files.
How can we align above commands in such a way that it also shows outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a bash script you could simply use the followin in the `stop_sdesk.sh` script.

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command="/server-group=sdesk:stop-servers"
```

Another option would be to use a CLI script file that contains the commands you want to execute then execute the script like:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=script.cli
```

Comment: How to pass credentials -> [disconnected /] connect
[domain@10.0.1.1:2090 /] /server-group=